# Android how to setup selection of options and viewing screen

Tags: android

I'm new to android and i'm trying to create an app which helps users with their workout. I understand that this question is quite big and maybe a little vague so I'll do my best to explain it in the hopes that I get an answer I can use.

The problem is that I have been struggling with how to set up the different activities and how they need to interact with one another. This is what it looks like:

```
 _________        _________       _________      
|         |      |         |     |         |
|         |      |         |     |         |
|         |      |         |     |         |
|    1    | ---> |     2   | --> |   3     |
|         |      |         |     |         |
|         |      |         |     |         |
|_________|      |_________|     |_________| 
   menu        options select   options shown
```

However AFTER the user has selected his options it should become:

```
 _________        _________    
|         |      |         | 
|         |      |         | 
|         |      |         | 
|    1    | ---> |     3   | 
|         |      |         |  
|         |      |         |    
|_________|      |_________|  
   menu          options shown
```

The user should also have the ability to go back to screen 2 from screen 3 to change his options. I simply don't know what the best approach for this is. Especially with the interaction of the back button.

Is it best to have 3 activities and try to link them together best I can or should I have 2 activities with a variable layout? Maybe by using fragments? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an `Activity` with `NavigationView` and `DrawerLayout` which brings menu feature and have a `FrameLayout` container where you can load fragments based on options. Your activity layout file can be something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemBackground="@color/white"
    app:itemTextAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

Comment: Why do I need the draweLayout? couldn't I just use the frameLayout in my existing layout?

Comment: DrawerLayout is for sliding menu drawer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SharedPreference.
In your Activity2, you need to get a sharedPreferenceString, if it's set to a value, you just start the activity3, otherwise let the user select, and set the sharedPreferenceString.
In your activity3, you can delete that sharedPreferenceString, so when you enter activity2, it would not be setted anymore, and you can let the user take the selection agian.
Here's the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. On Click Save destination activity name or number (identification) into preference
2. When user clicks check for preference and open that activity.
3. If null default value return by preference then open activity 2